# Render a component from a dynamic variable with Handlebars

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'd like to render a component that I will define within a variable.

I have a variable containing content like that:

*page.js*

```
Ember.Controller.extend({
   c: {
      'pageTitle': 'This is the title with a component {{my-component}}'
   }
});
```

*page.hbs*

```
<div>
   {{c.pageTitle}}
</div>
```

The `c` object is populated from an API call, from a content server. 
I would like to provide the capability to inject components from what is defined in the content.

Basically what I need would be to render 2 times, the first time to replace my `{{pageTitle}}` with the string, and the second time to replace `{{my-component}}` with the component.

What would be the best solution to do such a thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could render the component using the new {{component}} helper (in the latest version of Ember)

`{{component 'my-component'}}`

`{{component c.myPageTitleComponent}}`

For the text to be present, you could do two things:

### In your Template

You could implement the text directly in your template

`{{c.myPageTitleText}} {{component c.myPageTitleComponent}}`

### Using a Parent Component

You could implement a parent component:

`{{my-parent-component text=c.myPageTitleText componentName=c.myPageTitleComponent}}`

Then in 'my-parent-component', it would look like this:

`{{text}} {{component componentName}}`

This doesn't really make sense though unless you needed some custom logic in my-parent-component.

Comment: It's unfortunately not possible for me to separate the text to the component, those 2 things will come as only 1 variable. Otherwise I need to create 2 variables from this one variable in my controller, using something to parse it.